# How to add maxlength to an existing field using entity framework core 6?

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I'm struggling to apply a max length on an existing field using entity framework core 6 with sql server. I have this existing field:

```
[Required]
public string MyField { get; set; }
```

In the code behind the latest migration file, the field looks like this:

```
b.Property<string>("MyField")
    .IsRequired()
    .HasMaxLength(100000)
    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");
```

**My fist question is this**: How does `HasMaxLength` and `HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)")` play together here?

My goal is to apply a max length to this column, so that it's no longer of type `nvarchar(max)`, but has a max length of 20,000 (as my current biggest entry in the column is about 10,000 characters).

I was hoping this would be as easy as doing this:

```
[Required]
[MaxLength(20000)]
public string MyField { get; set; }
```

And then creating a new migration. However, the new migration (created with `dotnet ef migrations add RestrictMyFieldLength`) is completely empty.

**My second question is this**: Why is the migration that's created empty?

I've been googling trying to understand this, and I came across [this page](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/releases/tag/1.0.0#issue141). I tried deleting all my existing migrations and creating a new one (adding `[MaxLength(20000)]`), but it has no effect. The migration that's created still describes the field as `nvarchar(max)`.

I'm using these versions:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.0">
```

---

Update:

A colleague helped me figure out one blocker. I was configuring something different in my `DbContext` class, in the `OnModelCreating` method, which was overriding what I specified in the entity class. In the `OnModelCreating` method I had this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Property(x => x.MyField).HasMaxLength(100_000);
```

Commenting out that and then trying to create my migration then lead to a non-empty migration as expected. However, the migration that was created turned the columtype into a `nvarchar(255)`. In fact, I've experimented with different values for `[MaxLength(xxx)]`, and it seems that no matter what I enter, the resulting column type in the migration is `nvarchar(255)`. So my conclusion is that the `[MaxLength(xx)]` annotation is being ignored.

I am able to modify my `DbContext` class, in the `OnModelCreating` method. If I change `modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Property(x => x.MyField).HasMaxLength(100_000);` to `modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Property(x => x.MyField).HasMaxLength(10);` there, then the resulting migration file looks correct (the column type gets set to `nvarchar(10)`).

I would like however to be able to specify this in my entity class, using the annotation. Why is it not working?

---

Update 2:

Looks like I was ruining this for myself with:

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.RemovePluralizingTableNameConvention();
            modelBuilder.SetDefaultMaxStringLength(255);
...
```

So that whatever limit I was trying to impose with `MaxLength(x)` was being overridden by the `modelBuilder.SetDefaultMaxStringLength(255);`.

Comment: You better use `HasMaxLength` combined with `IsUnicode` (not `HasColumnType`).

Comment: Thanks for commenting! My goal is to avoid using `HasMaxLength`/`HasColumnType` explicitly myself. I would like to just use the annotation `[MaxLength(x)]` for some x, and then have Entity Framework figure out what the column type should be. Is that possible?

Comment: I tested and MaxLength is correctly interpreted. The generated field code is `MyField = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", maxLength: 20000, nullable: false)`

Comment: For information, `nvarchar(20000)` isn't supported in SQL Server. The max is `nvarchar(4000)`. After, it need specify `nvarchar(max)`. See this SQL Server doc for more information : [nchar and nvarchar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql)

Comment: Thanks for commenting! The 4000-limit is ok, but why does my `[MaxLength(100)]` annotation seem to be ignored by the created migration? No matter what x I put in `[MaxLength(x)]` in my entity class, it leads to the column type `nvarchar(255)`.

Comment: I can't repro that. A fluent configuration always overrides attributes, but when there's only an attribute it is used (up to 4000). Which EF version is this?

Comment: I've updated the question. I believe that `modelBuilder.SetDefaultMaxStringLength(255);` in onmodelcreate was overriding my attempts to use MaxLength.